# Advanced Regex help based on html comments

Tags: php, html, regex

I am trying to parse following html block using SimpleHTMLDOM, but failed to get full name and email from that, as page uses same table structure without any id or class name for different content blocks, but luckily pages uses different comment before each table. For example...

```
<!-- Showing Buyer Details -->
<table style="table-layout:fixed; width:100%; border: 1px solid #0000CD; border-collapse:collapse; margin: 0px; font-family: Arial,Helvetica; font-size: 10pt;background-color: #FFFFFF; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto " class="">
    <tbody class=""><tr class=""><td style="border:solid 1px #0000CD;padding: 5px; font-weight:bold" class="">Showing Buyer Details</td></tr>
    <tr class=""><td style="padding: 5px;" class="">
        <table border="0" style="font-family: Arial,Helvetica; font-size: 10pt;" class="">
                <tbody class=""><tr class=""><td valign="top" class=""><b class="">FULL NAME</b></td></tr>

                <tr class=""><td valign="top" class="">ADDRESS GOES HERE</td></tr>
                        <tr class="">
                <td valign="top" class="">(123) 456-7890</td>

            </tr>
                            <tr class=""><td valign="top" class="">(321) 098-0123 (Office Main Line)</td></tr>
                            <tr class="">
                    <td valign="top" class=""><a href="mailto:email@test.com" class="">email@test.com</a></td>

                </tr>
        </tbody></table>
    </td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

I want to get full Name and email address using regex or something good. This is really advanced for me, so i would appreciate any real help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: I have just tried to run `$html->find('comment')` using SimpleHTMLDomParser, but no luck what i really wanted. I am learning regex, please someone help.

Comment: the email address is easy, you could pull it out with `/mailto\:(.+)"/`

Comment: @castis yes i know i can search email using this regex but page any more email address, and i want to get just buyer email address. I know this is quite complex, but need real help.

Comment: How can i grab text between `<!-- Showing Buyer Details --> <table` and `</table>`

Answer (score 0):

You may try to select your table by regex

```
/<!-- Showing Buyer Details -->\s*(.+<\/table>\s*<\/td>\s*<\/tr>\s*<\/tbody>\s*<\/table>)/s
```

then, if you use SimpleHTMLDomParser, write (if i dont loos any level)

```
$html = str_get_html($str);
$name = $html->find("table", 1)->find("tr", 0)->find("td", 0)->find("b", 0)->innertext;
$address = $html->find("table", 1)->find("tr", 1)->find("td", 0)->innertext;
if (!$name || !$address) die("nof found");
echo $name . " " . $address;
```

Comment: Yes i have tried this but as i have mentioned, this page has various sections using same table structure. So only option is to get data using comment like <!-- Showing Buyer Details -->

Comment: You can take text between comment and </table></td></tr></tbody></table> by any text processing. then use parser for this fragment

Comment: wow you are awesome, let me try this code quickly, what about email, how can i get that as well?

Comment: just write accurately find

Comment: After getting that block, i tried. `$html->find('table tbody tr[1] td table tbody tr td b')->innertext;` but its failing.

Comment: try to step by step whatching inner or outter beginning from table... We loos any level, i think

Comment: I will be able to try only in 10 hours

Comment: @seoppc I was used to drive all the day, just now updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're going to need to get the right piece of the table, and then the email address in there. Not gonna lie to you, this would be easier with the classes and the rest of the HTML document.

Start by getting all the td elements, finding the one with the phrase "Showing Buyer Details". From there, you do some good old DOM traversal to get to the node you want.

```
$tds = $html->find('td');
$emails = array();
foreach( $tds as $td ){
    if($td->plaintext == "Showing Buyer Details"){
        $email_node = $td->parent()->next_sibling()->first_child()->first_child()->first_child()->last_child();
        array_push($emails, $email_node->plaintext);
    }
}
```

At this point, your $emails array should be full of email addresses. I went with the array because it wasn't really clear from your question if there were multiples of these tables. Anyway, it's not pretty to search all the `<td>` elements, but I don't see how it'd work using the comments.